# How long I can find 6-bytes sha-1 collision using this code?

Tags: python, collision, sha1

I need to find collision of "last 6-bytes of SHA-1 digest". Here is my Python code (have deleted unrelated part):

```
import hashlib
import os
import binascii

start_string = os.urandom(20)
x0 = binascii.hexlify(start_string)

hash_value = hashlib.sha1(x0)
x1 = hash_value.hexdigest()

while x0[28:]!=x1[28:]:
  x0 = x1
  x1_hash = hashlib.sha1(x0)
  x1 = x1_hash.hexdigest()
else:
  print x0
  print x1
```

I am using a Thinkpad T400 laptop (Intel Core 2 Duo 2.8GHz, 6 MB L2 cache, 800 MHz). How long it can find the collision? Anyway to improve the code to make it faster? (this Python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6 bytes of data is 2<sup>48</sup> (281474976710656) possibilities.  You'd expect to find a collision in about half that many checks on average, so about 140 trillion.  I get about 200000 SHA1/hexdigest operations per second on my machine (using Python), so I'd expect about 22 years of runtime.

If you don't specifically require the collision to be between two successive digests that you generate, you can greatly speed up the process by checking against *all* of the previously-generated digests (keep them in a set or dict).  (Look up the "birthday paradox" for details on just how much this helps.) This would run out of memory fairly quickly, but unless your laptop has the absolute minimum of RAM installed, it's likely you'd find a collision before that happens.  I'm coming up with an estimate of a minute or two of runtime, assuming 1-2 GB of available RAM.